# MaxentVariableSelection error reading files, error in file (file, 'rt') cannot open connection

Tags: r, maxent, dismo

I'm attempting to use the MaxentVariableSelection package to select the best set of environmental variables for a Maxent species distribution model.

I keep getting these two errors:

- > Error: Error reading files
- > Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning messages:

1. In dir.create(outdir):

   > `/Users/klairetrhodes/Desktop/Thesis/Output` already exists
2. In file(file, "rt"):

   > cannot open file `/Users/klairetrhodes/Desktop/Thesis/Output/maxentResults.csv`: No such file or directory

I have confirmed the following:

- all my environmental variables are ASCII files with common extent
- occurrence and background data is properly formatted
- file paths are accurate and exist
- I have run a simple Maxent model using dismo with a small set of variables -- that seemed to work fine

Comment: Could you post your code with a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

This error suggests that there's an issue with reading files. It could be due to incorrect file paths or incorrect file formats as you already suggest yourself.

try

```
    getwd()
```

to see where your working directory is located.

Create directories if not exist: Before trying to create a directory using dir.create(outdir), you can check if the directory already exists. If it doesn't exist, then create it.

```
    if (!file.exists(outdir)) {
      dir.create(outdir)
    }
```

Comment: The working directory seems to be set correctly.